# virtual destructor in c++

Tags: c++, virtual, virtual-destructor

In the code below, why is the `~Derived()` destructor called automatically?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout << "Calling ~Base()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
private:
    int* m_pnArray;

public:
    Derived(int nLength)
    {
        m_pnArray = new int[nLength];
    }

    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        cout << "Calling ~Derived()" << endl;
        delete[] m_pnArray;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived *pDerived = new Derived(5);
    Base *pBase = pDerived;
    delete pBase;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you prefer it wasn't?

Comment: I don't follow the question. Are you asking why deleting a `Derived` object should call the `Derived` destructor? Because that's how a `Derived` object is supposed to be destroyed. Or are you asking about the mechanism behind it, so that it works correctly with a `Base` pointer? It's exactly the same as any other virtual function call.

Comment: I just want to know the mechanism why the drived destructor is invoke ?

Comment: @Sajid: The mechanism is "that's what C++ does and it's a good thing too".

Answer (score 3):

Because your base class destructor is virtual

```
virtual ~Base();
```

the call to delete on a pointer to a base class results in virtual call to destructor and as any virtual call is dispatched to matching function in derived class. It is not only good, but necessary: otherwise the behavior is undefined.

This is crucial for a derived classes which destructor is not an empty function. Non-virtual call would otherwise result in calling base class destructor, derived resources being leaked, etc.

Comment: Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.  In any number of cases, it will crash the machine, for example.

Answer (score 1):

When you have at least one `virtual` function in a class, then the compiler creates a single table for the class listing the member function pointers.  Consider:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() { };

    int n_;
};
```

In *pseudo-code* you can imagine the compiler adding:

```
void* Base::__virtual_dispatch_table[] = { (void*)&Base::~Base };
```

Then, when you have an actual object of type `Base` it will have an extra hidden data member that points to the `Base::__virtual_dispatch_table` (the "VDT"):

```
Variable definition       Memory layout
-------------------       -------------
Base myBase;              int n_;
                          void** __p_vdt = Base::__virtual_dispatch_table;
```

Now, if you have a `Base* p` and `delete p;`, the compiler says "hey - it's `virtual` - I won't hardcode a call to `Base::~Base`, instead I'll generate code that does something like this pseudo-code:

```
void (Base::*p_destructor) = p->__p_vdt[0]
*p_destructor(p);   // "p" will provide the "this" value while the destructor runs
```

Why would you want to do all that?  Because when you come along with a `Derived` object...

```
class Derived: public Base
{
private:
    int* m_pnArray;
    ...
```

...the compiler can create a separate virtual dispatch table...

```
void* Derived::__virtual_dispatch_table[] = { (void*)&Derived::~Derived };
```

...andd lay out the Derived object's memory like this:

```
Variable definition       Memory layout
-------------------       -------------
Derived derived;          int n_;
                          void** __p_vdt = Derived::__virtual_dispatch_table;
                          int* m_pnArray;
```

Notice that the `__p_vdt` is in the same relative location within the object layout, but now points to the `Derived` class's virtual dispatch table?

Now, if you create a `Base*` to `derived`, the exact same code needed to call the destructor for a `Base` object, which - in case you've lost track - was...

```
void (Base::*p_destructor) = p->__p_vdt[0]
*p_destructor(p);   // "p" will provide the "this" value while the destructor runs
```

...can be run but will end up using the `Derived` object's `__p_vdt` value of `Derived::__virtual_dispatch_table`, and finding the `Derived` class's destructor.

Comment: vtables are an implementation detail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes... "I just want to know the mechanism" - I've given an indicative illustration of the universally used implementation mechanism, though certainly others are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because it allows you to treat any `Base` object (which may in fact be a `Derived`) as an object that you can delete.

In this case, if `delete pBase` didn't call the `Derived` destructor, the data held by `m_pnArray` would never get deleted, i.e. a "memory leak" would occur.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
delete pBase;
```

It looks at the virtual function table of pBase to find the appropriate destructor to begin unwinding at, and it finds Derived::~Derived and then works its way down the stack.